# Что за библиотека создает такие классные кнопки меню у телеграмм бота на python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, button, menu

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Синяя кнопка: Меню и выпадающие вверх айтемы, как сделать?

Comment: Разве это не просто список команд? Делается в бот фазере

Comment: Кнопки создает не библиотека на Python, а сам telegram. Он написан на Java. Если вам нужно реализовать подобную кнопку в telegram боте, то это другой вопрос.

Comment: @insolor, причем интересно, если писать бота на тех же java или c++\c# кнопки эти программно создать не проблема. через python я не видел такого, но и не интересовался в принципе.

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato, ну api один и тот же, значит если на python такого не делают, то просто в обертке над api для python это не реализовано.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Находим BotFather. `Меню` - `/setcommands`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Выбираем своего бота

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Пишем команды

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Профит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]